# AngularJS Iteratively Create Picklists with Options

Tags: json, angularjs, loops, picklist

I would like to know how to iteratively create picklists (dropdowns) from a json collection.

I have two desired columns, one representing the 'primary' category, and the other representing the 'secondary' category.

I'd like for the right column to have just a string for every 'primary' category and then the left column will have a picklist with options for secondary category. What i'm also trying to do is group this by type. So there will essentially be sections of picklists grouped by type. One section with two columns of 'string', and then another section below that one with two columns of 'number', etc.

--Numbers--

Column 1 || Column 2

Label || picklist

--Strings--

Column 1 || Column 2

Label || picklist

--Booleans--

Column 1 || Column 2

Label || picklist

```
    function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.players = [
    {type: 'String', org: 'primary', name: 'something__c', label: 'Something'},
    {type: 'Number', org: 'primary', name: 'something_else__c', label: 'Something Else'},
    {type: 'String', org: 'primary', name: 'obscure__c', label: 'Obscure'},
    {type: 'String', org: 'primary', name: 'else__c', label: 'Else'},
    {type: 'String', org: 'secondary', name: 'some__c', label: 'Some'},
    {type: 'Number', org: 'secondary', name: 'thing__c', label: 'Thing'},
    {type: 'Number', org: 'secondary', name: 'sanity_check__c', label: 'My Sanity'}
];
```

}

Using the tutorials i was only able to get as far as what is in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GV7KZ/5/

Thank you for any and all guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean 'org' instead of category, given that org is the only node with the values of 'primary' and 'secondary'. I thing perhaps you want to use 'filter' rather than your custom 'group by' filtering.

I've made some changes to your fiddle separating out the two. Let me know if this gets you closer to what you want.

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in players|filter:'primary'">
  <td>
      {{player.label}}
  </td>
<td>
    <select>
          <option ng-repeat="player in players|filter:'secondary'" value="{{player.name}}">{{player.label}}</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GV7KZ/6/